# I insert huge amounts of data to Solr7.4 in 4 hours and Solr query become very slow

Tags: performance, select, solr

When I add 500 million documents to Solr7.4 in 4 hours, the queries become very slow, but if I add this data over the course of several days，the queries are faster. Can any one can help me understand why? Thanks you so much.

Comment: Can you indicate (1) Which version of Solr you are using (2) How big the index is in GB/TB/PB (3) How much heap memory you are using and how many nodes (4) Please also provide sample queries. Thanks!

Comment: i use solr7.4, and 8 node, java heap size is 8G and direct memory is 4g

Comment: Thanks. During the batch load of documents when do you commit or do you? Also what are your autoCommit and autoSoftCommit settings?

Comment: i do not commit,it is autoCommit  in 15 seconds.

Comment: How about autoSoftCommit?